# Vector of structs

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a vector of structs in a loop however all elements of the vector end up having the same value (of the last one).

I thought that pushing back the element onto the vector would copy the struct.

Here is the code:

```
std::vector<struct ftpparse> parse_result;
std::istringstream is(ftp_result);

for (std::string line; getline(is, line); )
{
    struct ftpparse r;
    int found = ftpparse(&r, (char*)line.c_str(), line.size());
    if (!found)
        throw std::runtime_error("error parsing ftp list");
    else
        parse_result.push_back(r);
}
```

The struct and ftpparse function are provided in a seperate C library I am linking to.

**Edit 1**

Here is the ftp struct definition

```
struct ftpparse {
    char *name; /* not necessarily 0-terminated */
    int namelen;
    int flagtrycwd; /* 0 if cwd is definitely pointless, 1 otherwise */
    int flagtryretr; /* 0 if retr is definitely pointless, 1 otherwise */
    int sizetype;
    long size; /* number of octets */
    int mtimetype;
    time_t mtime; /* modification time */
    int idtype;
    char *id; /* not necessarily 0-terminated */
    int idlen;
};
```

Also if I remove the struct tag then I get the following error:

```
error: must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'ftpparse' in this scope
        ftpparse r = {};
        ^
        struct
```

Comment: Please post `ftpparse`.  Also, This is not 'C', so usage of `struct` all over the place is not necessary.

Comment: That copies the structure. Perhaps the stucture isn't correctly copyable; perhaps it's storing a pointer (as one might guess from the evil `(char*)` cast in your code), not a copyable string. Without seeing its definition, we can only guess.

Comment: How do you know that all of the elements end up having the same value? Are you sure that all of the `struct`s don't parse out to the same thing?

Comment: Does `ftpparse` duplicate string or does is take a pointer to it ?

Comment: Also, why did you name your function the same as the `struct` (ftpparse)?

Comment: This concerns me: `(char*)line.c_str()`. You probably have a const-incorrect function here. If not, you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't think he did. It looks like it's a [third party C library](http://cr.yp.to/ftpparse.html).

Comment: Yes it's that library I'm using, I wouldn't have named them the same myself.

Comment: @TobyCronin Well, your `struct` has pointers in it, and therefore will have issues when placing it in a vector by value.  Looking at the link that cdhowie gave, it sure looks like that's the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie depends on what you're doing with them. Treat them as POD (it's C after all) and they treat you as POD in return :). In other words, it isn't likely to be a problem in this case, since there is no implied ownership/resource management

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing vectors of structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166029/accessing-vectors-of-structs)

Comment: @sehe - I think the concern is this (if you go to the link):  `fp->name = buf + j + 1;`  In other words, `name` is holding onto a pointer within the `c_str()` that is sent to ftpparse.  That can't work out too good...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie welp! I visited that link now. I see "documentation" would be grotesque. And yes, you're right this library doesn't copy buffers safely internally. Now. Where do I get the bleach...

Comment: @TobyCronin - Which values are you observing within the struct that you say are the same?  If it's the non-pointer members of ftpparse, then the issue is that the ftpparse function isn't working, or you're not utilizing it correctly, or maybe the values *are* supposed to be the same.  If it's the pointer members, well, that's a different story...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's the pointer values that are the same, the other values are correct.

Comment: @TobyCronin - ok.  Would it be ok for you to copy the struct to one that is more vector friendly, and then push that struct in the vector?  In other words, use `std::string` instead of `char*` for the name and id?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes that would be ok but I'm not sure what the current problem is and how that would resolve it?

Comment: @TobyCronin - The problem is that the same `name` and `id` pointer value is being used for each item you placed in the vector, so you will not get unique names and id's.  What you probably want to do is store actual strings, not char*, and the answer I gave gives you an idea on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the original struct `ftpparse` contains char pointers, there will be issues storing copies in a vector, since a vector will not make deep copies.

What you could do is call the `ftpparse` function, but push_back a different struct that is basically a copy of the returned struct, but instead uses `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Here is an example:

```
// Our copy of the ftpparse struct 
struct ftpparseX {
    std::string name; 
    int flagtrycwd; 
    int flagtryretr; 
    int sizetype;
    long size; 
    int mtimetype;
    time_t mtime;
    int idtype;
    std::string id; 
    ftpparseX(const ftpparse& parse) : name(parse.name, parse.namelen), // we use 2-arg ctor
                                       id(parse.id, parse.idlen),   // we use 2-arg ctor
                                       flagtrycws(parse.flagtrycws),
                                       flagtryretr(parse.flagtryretr),
                                       sizetype(parse.sizetype),
                                       size(parse.size),
                                       mtimetype(parse.mtimetype),
                                       mtime(parse.mtime),
                                       idtype(parse.idtype) {}
};
//....

std::vector<ftpparseX> parse_result;
std::istringstream is(ftp_result);
for (std::string line; getline(is, line); )
{
    ftpparse r;
    int found = ftpparse(&r, (char*)line.c_str(), line.size());
    if (!found)
        throw std::runtime_error("error parsing ftp list");
    else
        parse_result.push_back(ftpparseX(r));
}
```

So basically, we do everything as usual, except that instead of a `push_back` of the `ftpparse`, we create an `ftpparseX` object and push that back instead, giving the constructor the `ftpparse` that we got back from the function.

This way you preserve the names and id's as `std::string` objects.  Note also how the strings are constructed using the 2 argument `std::string` constructor.  This respects that `name` and `id` have a length attribute, and are not necessarily null-terminated.